# Right usage of Where query in ORMLite for android

Tags: android, ormlite, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to generate a where query through ormlite.

eg:`Where name='Ärer' and (type='tt1' or type='tt2')`

But the result always apppears like this

```
SELECT * FROM `Test` WHERE ((((((`name` = 'Arer' AND `type` = 'tt1' ) OR `type` = 'tt2' ) OR `type` = 'tt3' ) OR `type` = 'tt4' ) OR `type` = 'tt5' ) )
```

This is java code that i have used to generate the above query

```
Where<Test, Integer> whereStatement = queryBuilder.where();

int cnt = 0;
String[] channelArray = getChannelSettingsForDB();
whereStatement.eq(NAME, "Arer")
    .and();
for (String channel : channelArray) {
    if (channel != null) {
        whereStatement.eq(TYPE, channel).or();
    }
```

Kindly let me know the right way of usage to generate a where query like this

```
Where name='Ärer' and (type='tt1' or type='tt2' or type='tt3' or type='tt4' or type='tt5')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the result always apppears like this
>
> ...  OR `type` = 'tt2' ) OR `type` = 'tt3' ...

Everytime ORMLite adds an `and()` or `or()` it is going to add parenthesis to be specific about the and/or arguments.  These methods take the previous clause and then do the operation with the next clause submitted.

In your case the first clause is the `eq(NAME, "Arer")` which gets and-ed with the first `eq(TYPE, channel)`.  This is not what you want.

> Kindly let me know the right way of usage to generate a where query like this ...

There are a couple of ways for you to do what you want to do.  The first way uses the `where.or(int)` feature which absorbs a number of clauses and separate them via `OR`.

```
whereStatement.eq(NAME, "Arer");
int channelCount = 0;
for (String channel : channelArray) {
    if (channel != null) {
        whereStatement.eq(TYPE, channel);
        channelCount++;
    }
}
if (channelCount > 0) {
    // or the last X clauses together
    whereStatement.or(channelCount);
    // and the channel ORs with the name
    whereStatement.and(2);
}
```

However you might consider using the `where.in(...)` method instead.  It won't handle nulls however so you will have to copy your array into a list or other iterable:

```
List<String> channels = new ArrayList<String>(channelArray.length);
for (String channel : channelArray) {
    if (channel != null) {
        channels.add(channel);
    }
}
if (!channels.isEmpty()) {
    // the IN replaces a bunch of ORs
    whereStatement.in(TYPE, channels);
    // and the channel IN with the name
    whereStatement.and(2);
}
```

For the various different ways to build queries, please RTFM:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/building-queries

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I will have check on this, Make it as accepted if everything is fine

Comment: Thanks :).it works..
Now a days you throw exception :
The SQL statement has not been finished since there are previous operations still waiting for clauses.
good to know :) thanks